# Add component to equation so a value turns into a negative?

Tags: probability, statistics, recreational-mathematics, order-statistics

This is a variation of another question I posted. The difference is that here we have an equation that *mostly* works. We just need help finding how to push a *Case*.

Honestly, we're just trying out different formulas, because we *know* how the ranking should look like, but we don't know how to implement.

I work at the NY Times, and these "Cases" are places that we are studying to see the ranking. `In` & `Out` is the total number of subscriptions for all 5 months for a case (Ins = new subscriptions and Outs = subscriptions that left).

The months column shows if we won or lost: a **1** means that we had more ins than outs and **-1** means that we had more Outs than Ins.

For us, In - Out is the most important, so `Case1` and `Case2` are the worse off. Coincidentally, case 1 is worse than case 2 because case 1 lost all 5 months.

But look at `Case 6`: even though it is the *best* case based on Ins, it's lost 3 months in a row. I want to make the value in `Rank` negative without *greatly* affecting everything else. That way `Case 6` is higher than `Case 5' since`Case 5` has a winning streak.

What can I add to the equation so that the *Rank* of *Case 6* is negative but everything else is not affected too much by this change?

This is the formula we're using:

```
(Ins-Outs)*(Outs/TotalOuts)
```

So for case 1: `(390-1010)*(1010/4859) = -128.874254`

```
          In     Out    Jan    Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Rank          In-Out
Case 1    390    1010   -1     -1    -1    -1    -1    -128.874254  -620
Case 2    390    1010   0      -1    -1    -1    -1    -128.874254  -620
Case 3    400    1000   -1     -1    -1    -1    -1    -123.482198  -600
Case 4    360    359    1      1     1     -1    -1    0.073883515  1
Case 5    180    120    -1     1     1     1     1     1.481786376  60
Case 6    1400   1360   1      1     -1    -1    -1    11.19571928  40
Total:    3120   4859
```

I wouldn't blame anyone if the question was downvoted lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add up the month 1's and -1's for each case value, multiply by 5, and add to score:

New formula: (Ins-Outs)*(Outs/TotalOuts) +(sum of months)*5

Ex. Case 5: $1.481786376 +(-1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1)5 = 1.481786376 + 15 = 16.48176376$
    Case 6: $11.19571928 +( 1 + 1 - 1 - 1 - 1)5 = 11.19571928 - 5 = 6.19571928$

Just BTW-- case 4 would get a little boost from its winning streak of 3, but if you change the multiplicative factor of 5, you can adjust the size of boosts given for winning streaks by this method.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't add all the months because then I wouldn't be considering the consecutive losses.

Comment: 1+1+1+(-1)+(-1) would be the same as (-1)+(-1)+1+1+1, and that's not correct.

Comment: adding the months doesnt take into account consecutive wins and losses but it does consider losses to be just as bad as wins are good. It seems from the second comment that you want to try and predict future outcomes of the case based on past consecutive wins or losses, so you could do that by increasing the value of the months from left to right. Jan = +/-5 Feb = +/-6 Mar= +/-7.. etc.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you use 5?

Comment: 5 is just a number i chose randomly, the larger you make it, the more affect consecutive wins and losses will have on rank, the smaller you make it, the less affect it will have. So feel free to change it to fine tune your equation